# Detectar desde donde es llamado un evento - C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un evento `FormClosing` el cual se invoca al presionar la X de cerrar de la ventana y también cuando ejecuto el comando `this.Close()`.

El asunto es que quiero detectar de cual de las 2 formas fue invocado este evento.

Codio del evento.

```
private void MDIPrincipal_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea salir del programa?", "Salir del Programa",
     MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
    else e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Utilizo este código para que me pregunte ¿Desea salir del programa?, antes de cerrar el formulario. Pero no quiero que me pregunte al utilizar `this.Close()` ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo?.

**Más Detalles**.

En caso de que no se pueda detectar desde donde fue invocado, se me ocurrió una solución alternativa. Utilizar un parámetro extra `string detonador`.

Por ejemplo.

```
private void MDIPrincipal_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e, string detonador = "")
{
    if (detonador != "")
    {
        //Código aquí...
    }
}
```

Pero no se como implementarlo. O también desactivando este evento para que no se invoque.

Ejemplo.

```
Event.MDIPrincipal_FormClosing.Disable();
This.Close();
```

El punto es que quiero que el formulario se cierre sin que me pregunte al utilizar `this.Close()`.

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizar el `Environment.Exit(1)` directamente en vez del `this.close()`?

Comment: Porque quiero cerrar solo ese formulario. Por eso uso `this.Close()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar un este código.

```
         FormClosing -= MDIParent1_FormClosing;
```

Donde += NameForm_FormClosing;`es para activar el evento y`
 -= NameForm_FormClosing;` para desactivarlo.

En tu caso lo pondrías en el evento `Click`  del botón para cerrar sesión

Comment: Gracias @Leonel me ha resultado de mucha utilidad.